# How to get Facebook video privacy settings using graph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, video, koala

How do I get a Facebook video object privacy settings with GRAPH API?
(I'm using Ruby Koala).
Could only find FQL solution ([here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8226699/check-photo-privacy-for-a-user))

Thanks,
Moozly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the FQL solution is the only way to go this. You cannot get Privacy information for an object using a Graph API call.

Comment: Is it true again in 2020?

Comment: The FB Graph API has been updated to return the `privacy` object for Videos, so FQL is no longer required: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/